# Not storing custom state in sessionStorage in react-router

Tags: react-router, history.js

I am using the `onEnter` functionality on the routes to add some custom logic on authorization in the front-end. Specifically-

1. If an unauthorized user lands on a page that needs authorization, store the nextPath in a new location state `nextPathname` and redirect the user to login page. On login, a user will be redirected to the `nextPathname`. Here, I am explicitly storing the `nextPathname` in the redux-store.

`function requireAuth(nextState, replace) {
      if (!s.isLoggedIn(store.getState())) {
        replace({
          pathname: '/login',
          state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
        })
      }
    }`

2. If an unapproved user lands on a page that he is not allowed, store the path name at `unauthroizedPathname` and take the user to a new page and show a relevant error message including the page name. Here, I am just displaying the error message with dismisses after a few seconds.

````

```
function requireValidation(nextState, replace) {
  if (!s.isFinancierVerified(store.getState())) {
    replace({
      pathname: '/dashboard',
      state: { unauthroizedPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
    })
  }
}
```

````

I need these states to be present only for the nextPath and not after that. However, it looks like these states are saved in the sessionStorage so they persist even through page reloads.

Is there a way I can disable these states to be stored in sessionStorage? Or any other way I can accomplish the tasks mentioned above?

[image: Custom states stored in session storage]